# The authenticated client is not authorized to use this authorization grant type

Tags: wso2

I have been building a React based SPA to consume an API deployed in WSO2 API Manager.
I did everything mentioned in this excellent tutorial :
https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2019/08/building-a-react-based-single-page-application-to-consume-an-api-deployed-in-wso2-api-manager/

So i am using OAuth2 implicit grant type.
However i have this error message after i reach the /authorize request :

```
Object { error: "unauthorized_client", error_description: "The authenticated client is not authorized to use this authorization grant type", session_state: "485a86f974459bfb9cdd7a845341e88bcc4cfedc242cb15cfc2956e131a7c44c.SMRIHTA_L6wA3yqb59iSSA", sp: "admin_ReactApp_PRODUCTION", tenantDomain: "carbon.super" }
Auth.js:26
```

What could be wrong ?
In my dev portal interface (https://localhost:9443/devportal), i have noticed all but the implicit grant types are listed. It is not showing in the list.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The above error only comes if the following method returns false.

`https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/authz/handlers/AbstractResponseTypeHandler.java#L123`

Hence, The only possibilities are the following.

1. Implicit grant type is not enabled for the application.
2. Authorization request does not contain the response type as response_type=id_token

1.Enabling implicit grant in dev portal

In the application section. add the callback URL which you defined in the authorization request. Then the implicit tick will appear and you will be able to select the grant.

[refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tGJ7.png)

please re-check the authorization request which you are initiating from the client application.

```
https://localhost:8243/authorize
scope=openid
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/playground2/oauth2client
&nonce=13e2312637dg136e1
&client_id=mzdQQ0RZOIqAf549ucIImB4h0SIa
```

If the above two are good. you should be able to resolve the error.

Thanks
Dileepa

Comment: Thanks for helping. I went to the dev portal interface, in the application section and I do not see the implicit checkbox. This is what i get : (i notice the title is Production OAuth2 Keys)  : <img src="https://imgur.com/a/rk2jhTh">  Any idea why it is different ?

Comment: can you login to the /carbon console. navigate to the service providers section and select the ReactApp application. From their select Inbound/Oauth and enable implicit grant type. please refer to the screenshots https://imgur.com/a/sSbAqlx

Comment: please try the above and share the feedback

Comment: I did what you asked and i still do not see the implicit checkbox. I restarted everything (publisher, portal and carbon), same thing. However i tried the application (using the REACT app as a client) and it works now. See the screenshots here : https://imgur.com/gallery/l6xdq70 How come the implicit checkbox still does not appear however ? Thanks again for helping.

Comment: That is strange. by any chance have you disabled the implicit grant. please do check whether you have disabled the grant from deployment.toml. [oauth.response_type.token]
enable = false

[oauth.response_type.id_token]
enable = false

[oauth.response_type.id_token_token]
enable = false

Comment: Is that file the one located here ? 
C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\3.2.0\repository\conf
If yes, there are no such properties (oauth.response_type.token, oauth.response_type.id_token and oauth.response_type.id_token_token)